# Iterate through a custom Parse column in Swift app

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I want to know how I could store the entire custom column (the user `Pointer<_User>` column from a custom class) and put them all in an array variable so that I can see if a the user exists in that class or not. This is what I have:

Old Code

```
    var objectUserIdArray = [String]()
    let objectUserIdQuery : PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "Scores")

    objectUserIdQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects : [PFObject]? , error : NSError?) -> Void in

        var objectID = objects! as [PFObject]

        for i in 0..<objectID.count {
            objectUserIdArray.append(objectID[i].objectId!)
        }

        for _ in objectID {
            print(objectUserIdArray)
        }
```

New Code

```
func saveScoresOnParse() {
    objectUserIdQuery.whereKey("User", equalTo: PFObject(withoutDataWithClassName: "_User", objectId: userID))

    objectUserIdQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects : [PFObject]? , error : NSError?) -> Void in
        if error == nil {

            //var objectID = objects! as [PFObject]

            /*for i in 0..<objectID.count {
                self.objectUserIdArray.append( objectID[i].objectId! )
            }*/

            for _ in objects! {
                print(objects)
            }

            // The score key has been incremented
            for (var i = 0 ; i < self.objectUserIdArray.count ; i++) {
                if self.userID != objects![i] {
                    print("New Scores")
                    print("R: \(self.rightAnswers)")
                    print("W: \(self.wrongAnswers)")
                    print("S: \(self.skippedQuestions)")
                    self.scores["User"] = PFUser.currentUser()
                    self.scores["Right"] = self.rightAnswers
                    self.scores["Wrong"] = self.wrongAnswers
                    self.scores["Skipped"] = self.skippedQuestions
                    self.scores.saveInBackground()

                } else if self.userID == objects![i] {
                    print("Updated Scores")
                    self.scores.incrementKey("Right", byAmount: 1)
                    self.scores.incrementKey("Wrong", byAmount: 1)
                    self.scores.incrementKey("Skipped", byAmount: 1)
                    print("R: \(self.rightAnswers)")
                    print("W: \(self.wrongAnswers)")
                    print("S: \(self.skippedQuestions)")
                    self.scores.saveInBackgroundWithBlock {
                        (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                        if (success) {
                            // The score key has been incremented
                        } else {
                            // There was a problem, check error.description
                        }
                    }

                } else {
                    print("Error")
                }
            }
        } else {
            print(error)
        }
    }
```

But it only stores the `objectId` column and not the `Pointer<_User>` column. I know this because when I print the stuff that is inside, it prints out the objectIds.

This is what happens, instead of just updating the current user's scores, it just makes new ones. I want the if statement to check if the user already exists in that column and if it does updates the scores and if it doesn't, make new ones. (The new code's if statement doesn't work, i have to bring it out for it to save...)

[image: stuff that happens]

Comment: What do you want to store? The PFObject?

Comment: I want to store the entire objectIDs pointing to the user. Not the ones created in the new custom class. Like I want to store the values in the second column, or third or fourth. Not the entire row's objectID @Paulw11

Comment: So, you simply need to access the column that contains the user objects.  Something like `objectID[i]["user"].objectId`

Comment: Yeah. However I tried that method it gave me an error @Paulw11

Comment: Provide the code you have tried and the error message.  You will need to unwrap the optional and possibly downcast as well.

Comment: @Paulw11 I have it as the code above now. Which stores each rows new object id when created. No it gave me an error that like it didn't work. As if you can't you on an string variable.count. Like it gave me that kind of error.

Comment: What is the name of your pointer column in Scores?  `user` ?

Comment: @Paulw11 I updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

Your updated question make clearer what you are actually wanting to do;

Save or update a user's scores in your Parse Score object.  To do this, there is no reason to retrieve any object Ids or loop through any results. More often than not you don't do use Object Ids explicitly when using Parse; you can simply pass the object itself with Parse working out the references for you.

I am not sure how you exactly want to change the scores; in your code above you increment in one case but set the scores explicitly in another, but the code below shows the general approach.

If you are frequently or repeatedly going to update a score record then you could make your code more efficient by holding a reference to the Scores object in a property after you find it the first time and simply update & save it subsequently.

```
func saveScoresOnParse() {
    if let currentUser=PFUser.currentUser() {
       let scoreQuery= PFQuery(className: "Scores")
       scoreQuery.whereKey("User",equalTo:currentUser)
       scoreQuery.getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (object : PFObject? , error : NSError?) -> Void in
           if error == nil {
              var scoreObject=object ?? PFObject.objectWithClassName("Scores")
              if (scoreObject["User"]==nil) {
                 scoreObject["User"]=currentUser
              }
              scoreObject["Right"]=self.rightAnswers
              scoreObject.saveInBackground()
           } else {
              print(error)
           }
       }
    } else {
       print("No current user!")
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the error I get: 2015-11-11 14:48:05.872 YPWP[65655:4935183] [Error]: pointer field User needs a pointer value (Code: 102, Version: 1.9.0)
Optional(Error Domain=Parse Code=102 "pointer field User needs a pointer value" UserInfo={code=102, temporary=0, error=pointer field User needs a pointer value, NSLocalizedDescription=pointer field User needs a pointer value})

Comment: Where do you get this?  When querying or when saving?

Comment: The error just shows up when I press skip on the app, so when it's trying to save the score.

Comment: That error occurs when you set a field to an object ID, not an object.  Can you set a breakpoint and single-step through the function?  You will need to set a second breakpoint on the line `if error==nil` to stop inside the query result closure